# Save Formset in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have a formset from a model, but when I try to save more than one formset I get the error:

> KeyError at /auditoria/auditoria_tab/ 'id_control'

My view:

```
@staff_member_required
def AuditoriaView(request):
   class RequiredFormset(BaseFormSet):
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(RequiredFormset,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
         for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted =  False

   auditoriaFormset = formset_factory(AuditoriaForm,max_num=31,formset=RequiredFormset)

   if request.method == 'POST':
      usuario = request.user
      accion = 'Registro nuevo Detalle de Auditoria'
      formset  = auditoriaFormset(request.POST)
      for form in formset.forms:
         if formset.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            #obj.id_control = control
            obj.auditor = request.user
            obj.save()
   else:
      formset = auditoriaFormset()

   return render_to_response('audit_auditoria.html',
                              {'formset':formset},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My form:

```
class AuditoriaForm(forms.ModelForm):
   id_control = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Control.objects.all().order_by('nombre'),\
                                       required=True,label='Control', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   id_analista = UserModelNameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=False),\
                                          required = True, label='Analista', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   fecha = forms.DateField(widget=DateInputCustom())
   id_tipoerror = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TipoError.objects.all(),required=True, label='Tipo Falla', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   id_sharepoint = forms.IntegerField(label='Sharepoint', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','style': 'width:80px'}))
   id_estado = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Estado.objects.all(),required=True, label='Estado', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   observaciones = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5,'cols':30}))

   class Meta:
      model = DetalleAuditoria
      exclude = ('auditor',)

   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
      super(AuditoriaForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
      self.helper = FormHelper(self)

   def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super(AuditoriaForm,self).clean()
      idc = cleaned_data['id_control']
      fechac = cleaned_data['fecha']

      try:
         DetalleAuditoria.objects.get(id_control = idc,fecha = fechac )
         raise forms.ValidationError('Esta Incidencia ya ha sido registrada')
      except DetalleAuditoria.DoesNotExist:
         pass

      return cleaned_data
```

Template:

```
<form id="form_audit" class="form" method="post" action="/auditoria/auditoria_tab/">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered">
              {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset.forms %}
               <thead>
                <th class="info"colspan="6">
                  <label >{{ form.id_control.label|capfirst }} </label>
                  {{ form.id_control }}
                </th>
               </thead>
               <thead>
               <th>{{ form.id_analista.label|capfirst }}</th>
               <th>{{ form.id_sharepoint.label|capfirst }}</th>
               <th>{{ form.fecha.label|capfirst }}</th>
               <th>{{ form.id_tipoerror.label|capfirst }}</th>
               <th>{{ form.id_estado.label|capfirst }}</th>
               <th>{{ form.observaciones.label|capfirst }}</th>
              <thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %} formset_row">
               <td>{{ form.id_analista }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.id_sharepoint }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.fecha }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.id_tipoerror }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.id_estado }}</td>
               <td>{{ form.observaciones }}</td>
              </tr>
               {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Registrar">
            </form>

{% block extra_js %}
<script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/jquery.formset.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function renewDatePickers() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startDate: "2014-01-01",
        endDate: "2020-01-01",
        autoclose: true
    });
   }

   $(renewDatePickers);

    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar Detalle Auditoria',
        deleteText: 'Eliminar',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
        added: renewDatePickers
    });

</script>

{% endblock extra_js %}
```

how can I use the field ID_CONTROL from the first formset in the other formsets, when I want to save the data.

I am not sure if I am using in the right way the formsets?.

Any advice

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE:
I get the error in the "clean" function. When the view try to save the second formset ther error appeare in this line in the:

```
  idc = cleaned_data['id_control']
```

In the error page I can see the post and I can see for the first formset the id_control value, but for the second formset I see all the fields except id_control.

Comment: can you share full error messages?

Comment: @Jayground that is the all message I get. The error show me an exception in the clean function from the form, I think in the second formset don't have value for id_control

Comment: Hard to follow, please try to build a minimal reproducible version.

Comment: can you print(formset) in if setence(request.method="POST") after `formset  = auditoriaFormset(request.POST)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me a non sense to put the same control id into the next forms in that way.
Anyway, to solve what you asking for, this should be valid (having different "fecha" value the forms):

```
   id_control=None
   if request.method == 'POST':
      usuario = request.user
      accion = 'Registro nuevo Detalle de Auditoria'
      formset  = auditoriaFormset(request.POST)

      for counter, form in enumerate(formset.forms):
         if formset.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            if counter>0:
                obj.id_control = id_control
            obj.auditor = request.user
            obj.save()
            if counter==0:
                id_control=obj.id_control
   else:
      formset = auditoriaFormset()
```